# Amazon EC2 terminated instance (Free Tier)

Tags: amazon-ec2, instance

I am using free tier on Amazon. I had one micro instance, which I terminated. If I create another one (micro) instance, will Amazon start charging me? 
I can still see my terminated instance in the instances list, but I cannot start or reboot it. Can I somehow delete it from the list?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AWS charges you only for instances that are running, and as long as you only have one running at any one time you will not be charged. And NO operations can be performed on terminated instances, which disappear 1 hr after terminated.

**UPDATE: There was a Price change**
Now free tier gets you a "micro instance" for 750hrs/mo for 12 months. Over 750hrs or after 1 yr, not free. And as these posts get old, probably best to just look it up yourself here:
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Comment: You will be charged when you go over 750 machine hours for t1.micro instance.
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Comment: Not just for running instances, Amazon also charges for the disk space used by the Volume of your Instance even if your Instance is not running.  This will appear on your bill after you use up your Free Tier hours for new AWS customers.

Answer (score 48):

You cannot perform any operations on the terminated instance. It is displayed in the list until one hour after deletion.  After that time it will be removed from the list.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
  var terminateInstancesRequest = new TerminateInstancesRequest();
    terminateInstancesRequest.InstanceIds = new List<string>() { InstanceId };
    bool isError = true;
    while (isError)
    {
     try
     {
         amazonEc2client.TerminateInstances(terminateInstancesRequest);
         isError = false;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
         isError = true;
     }
    }
```